# How do I transition multiple installations to a single Multisite installation?

Tags: multisite, configuration, customization

I have a client who runs 8 different blogs, currently on 8 separate installations of WordPress.  I'm trying to encourage them to move to a single MS installation instead to make it easier (mostly on me) to maintain the different sites, themes, and mix of plug-ins.  Unfortunately, I shied away from MU for the longest time, and now I have no idea where to start with MS.

I've used [WP-Hive](http://wp-hive.com/) in the past because it allowed me to use multiple domains with one installation of WordPress (I don't like sub-folder blogs or sub-domains sites).  This client project, if we go forward, will be a similar setup - multiple single-domain blogs hosted on a single WordPress installation.

So what steps should I follow to

1. Set up Multisite​ - I know how to install it, but how should I configure it considering I want to use it for separate domains, not sub-folders or sub-domains?
2. Move content - I assume the regular WP export-import process will work?
3. Map the domains to their new home on the new installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To map your domains, you can consider to use the [WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) which works with wordpress 3.0 as well.

Otto has a tutorial online: [WordPress 3.0: Multisite Domain Mapping Tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/)

Next to that Import/Export should mainly do the job to transfer the sites.