# Full Domain Mapping with WP3 in Multiuser Mode

Tags: multisite

You may have learned already to reconfigure your WP3 so that it loads in MU mode, and set it for subdomains.

Evidently my Dallas client claims that **instead of just subdomains**, there are some tricks you can do (cpanel? wp-admin? plugin? config file change?) **to make a full domain like example.com for a subdomain, instead of having a subdomain like blog1.example.com**.

Is this true? How is it achieved? Does it have any caveats that you can think of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map regular domains to a WordPress Multisite installation using the [WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

There's also a great tutorial available: [WordPress 3.0: Multisite Domain Mapping Tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/)

For reference ... [I asked a similar question yesterday](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/738/how-do-i-transition-multiple-installations-to-a-single-multisite-installation).  I have a client who hosts multiple blogs with unique domains, but it becomes a hassle to maintain each one separately.  I'm working with them to transition to a Multisite setup instead - single superuser admin, single set of plug-ins, single set of themes, single set of core files ... much easier to upgrade and maintain.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here is another tutorial on how to setup WordPress Multisite with multiple domains: [WordPress 3.0 Multisite With Multiple Domains Setup](http://www.interconnectit.com/840/wordpress-3-0-multisite-with-multiple-domains-setup/)